# About html5 canvas figure

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas

If I am not sure whether I am going to receive a rectangle or rhombus or circle or trapezium or polygon coordinate from the server, then which figure should I select to draw an object on canvas in Angular framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following things to avoid any confusion.

- Each diagram has specific set of coordinates. like r**ectangle has 4, square has 4, circle has infinite points** (has a center and a radius used to draw).
- So you can either check in the javascript for which diagram you are getting the coordinates, and fetch the coordinates from server response accordingly.
- Or you can put an additional attribute of **diagram type** in server response and filter it in javascript.
- It will be easy for you to send a diagram type from server and you can use

> switch statements or If conditions to check the diagram type and fetch the results from server response accordingly, if you receive response in json then it will be like.

```
if(response.data.diagram_type === "square"){
   // now you will know what attributes you need for this shape
   // assuming that you have sent coordinates in an array from server and each array has (x, y) so create objects {} not arrays [].
   var coordinate_0 = {};
   var coordinate_1 = {};
   var coordinate_2 = {};
   var coordinate_3 = {};
   coordinate_0 = data.response.coordinates[0];
   coordinate_1 = data.response.coordinates[1];
   coordinate_2 = data.response.coordinates[2];
   coordinate_3 = data.response.coordinates[3];
}else if (response.data.diagram_type === "circle"){
   var coordinate_center = {};
   coordinate_center = data.response.circle_center;
   var radius= data.response.circle_radius;
   // create your shape accordingly.
}
// similarly for other diagram.

// hope it helps.
```